# Echo shell script execution time

Tags: bash, shell

I have this shell script which executes the following command:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e  " {\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"mypasswd\",\"data\"" > $file
```

How do I need to adjust this in order to measure the execution time and echo both, execution time and script output to a file?

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `time` command. For example:

```
time (
    echo -e  "$(date) \n--\n{\"username\":\"user\",\"password\":\"mypasswd\",\"data\": [$formated]}\n --"
) > $outputFileName 2>&1
```

Comment: Could you translate the question? I don't get it

Comment: @MichelFeldheim my understanding is that Mohamed Ahmed wants to time the execution of his script. Obviously his script will do more than this that’s why I put parentheses around so that he can easily insert additional code.

Comment: @MichelFeldheim  true , and your answer correct , put its print timing    in terminal,  not  into same out pput file